# 301 redirect в .htaccess на универсальное доменное имя

Tags: seo, .htaccess, редирект, redirect

Есть такая запись в .htaccess:

> Redirect 301 /ru http://example.com

Она перенаправляет с линка http://example.com/ru на линк http://example.com. Вопрос: как изменить эту строчку, чтоб она работала с любым доменным именем, а не только с example.com.
(т.е. как бы взять первую часть запроса в котором содержится доменное имя и перенаправить на него)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте `Redirect 301 /ru /`

Answer (score 1):

Если у Вас доступен mod_rewrite, тогда смотрите в сторону RewriteCond и RewriteRule. Вот пример редиректа с www.site.com на http://site.com

```
#включаем mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on
#условие
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site.com [NC]
#правило
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```